# Django ImportError: No module named myapp_name.settings

Tags: python, django

I was editing an old project that could be used for a new functionality but now I can not get it going. I have tried almost all the solutions I've seen on the web but I have not guessed right. The repository where the project is is this:

https://github.com/AlejandroFerroBejerano/QARxisAccesControl.git

and when I try to run '$ python manage.py migrate' I get the error: ImportError: No module named QARxisAccessControl.settings

You can tell me where the error is? How can i launch the python manage.py migrate command without errors?

I let you the repo tree since:

~/Proyectos/QARxisAccesControl/src/prototypes/QARxisAccessControl$

[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TVVu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your module directory is misspelled as it's missing an `s` in the word `Access`. Your Directory structure should look like this:

```
 + QARxisAccessControl
    - settings.py
 - main
 - manage.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main',
...
]
```

to this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
...
]
```

Also, make sure you change your secret key!

Also, make sure you change your directory name (credit to @charliebeckwith)

Comment: Both are same. If you specify the name directly, `main` or if you specify the class name `main.apps.MainConfig`. In both case the app is installed.

Comment: Cool I didn't know that.  I just assumed you had to do it my way since that is how its done in the docs